# How to navigate from one activity to another in android kotlin?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm a beginner android app developer and exploring this field

I tried documentation but it was bit hard to understand for a complete beginner like me.

Comment: Please show which part of the offical documentation  is unclear for you ... and which code snippet in the docs i not working

Comment: @Selvin waste of time talking to u 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple you can find it very easily, if you search on `Google`

```
Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("data", "here") //if you want to pass any data 
            startActivity(this)
}
```